# Should no_expiry be used for OAuth to only identify accounts?

Tags: support, api, oauth

I'm about to integrate StackExchange as an OAuth provider into my web application. The documentation states:

> `expires` will only be set if scope does not include `no_expiry`, the use of which is strongly advised against unless your app truly needs perpetual access.

My app only needs that token to identify a user logging in. However, it seems I would need to make a request to `/me` every time a user logs in if I don't use no_expiry, because I can't identify a user using the access token if it changes once a day. So what's the preferred way of doing this? Adding `no_expiry` even if I don't need "offline access" or making a second request every time?